# Using awk for conditional find/replace

Tags: bash, sed, awk, hunspell, spell-checking

I want to solve a common but very specific problem: due to OCR errors, a lot of subtitle files contain the character "I" (upper case i) instead of "l" (lower case L).

My plan of attack is:

1. Process the file word by word
2. Pass each word to the hunspell spellchecker ("echo the-word | hunspell -l" produces no response at all if it is valid, and a response if it is bad)
3. If it is a bad word, AND it has uppercase Is in it, then replace these with lowercase l and try again.  If it is now a valid word, replace the original word.

I could certainly tokenize and reconstruct the entire file in a script, but before I go down that path I was wondering if it is possible to use awk and/or sed for these kinds of conditional operations at the word-level?

Any other suggested approaches would also be very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need more than bash for this:

```
while read line; do
  words=( $line )
  for ((i=0; i<${#words[@]}; i++)); do
    word=${words[$i]}
    if [[ $(hunspell -l <<< $word) ]]; then
      # hunspell had some output
      tmp=${word//I/l}
      if [[ $tmp != $word ]] && [[ -z $(hunspell -l <<< $tmp) ]]; then
        # no output for new word, therefore it's a dictionary word
        words[$i]=$tmp
      fi
    fi
  done
  # print the new line
  echo "${words[@]}"
done < filename > filename.new
```

It does seem to make more sense to pass the whole file to hunspell, and parse the output of that.

Comment: Hi @glenn! +1!
Ha, ha! I didn't know _hunspell_ handled punctuation, I'll delete my post :)

Comment: That is pretty much what I ended up doing in bash, though I checked for the presence of an "I" first before doing the first hunspell test.  Then did up to two more hunspell passes: the second with all "I"s replaced with l's, and the third with all but the first "I" replaced with l's (for words like "IdIot").  This produced a solution good enough for my needs, though of course it was quite intensive processor-wise - a 120KB file took about 2 minutes on an i7-920 to process.  I'll certainly accept the answer if no more efficient one comes along.

Comment: The more efficient answer would be to something like `hunspell -options file | parse_the_output > new_file` -- only has to spawn hunspell once instead of once for every word in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. *Fix the problem closer to where it originates*, i.e. near the OCR Software. Can it be made to consult a dictionary and don't even come up with non-words containing 'I'? If not, try a different OCR program that can.
2. Running each word through hunspell creates a process for each word, which is a **massive** waste of CPU cycles. *Try using several passes*, where the first pass finds all 'I' words, then filter out correct words, then replace each correctable word.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  You are certainly right about (1) but unfortunately I only have the resulting .SRT file to work with.  I made (2) slightly better by limiting hunspell use only to words containing "I", but you're right in that it's still computationally expensive.  I'll investigate whether I can reconcile the hunspell output of a whole file with the original file.